# import ascii or binary grid data into R

Tags: r, import, binary, ascii

I'm trying to import 2016 bathymetry grid data, either ascii or binary, (downloaded from https://niwa.co.nz/our-science/oceans/bathymetry/download-the-data?sid=23250) into R, however after a couple of days struggling I still don't succeed. Firstly I'am struggling to import the data into R, I read.table(.., nrows=x) worked more or less, but secondly I don't know how I should handle the data and create a df with the coordinates and the associated depth with it.

Thanks in advance, Bram

Comment: Which file are you having trouble with? (That link just brings up a webpage.)

Comment: 2016 and then one of the grid files.

Comment: So why aren't you using a link like: ftp://ftp.niwa.co.nz/bathymetry/NZBathy_DTM_2016_ascii_grid.zip ? Admittedly it is a rather slow server.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm actually doing, sorry if that was unclear. My question is how about to proceed from there? I would like to create a depth grid of 1by1 km, but I can't figure it out how to handle those files in R..

Comment: It's unclear if you have yet downloaded one of those files. It took me almost an hour to download one. If you have downloaded one, then where are you experiencing difficulties. The answers to these questions should be in an [edit] to your question body.